# GCD global queue control

Tags: swift, concurrency, queue, grand-central-dispatch

My app demands some simple concurrency, so I've chosen GCD for these proposes. 
Everything works great, I use one global queue with a high priority (one of the Apple's default). But I'm stuck in queue control. I need force cancelation of all processes in this queue after some user actions.
Furthermore, is it possible to check if one of the global queues has any tasks for a moment? That will help me not to populate the same tasks if user would ask to.

Comment: Use NSOperationQueue if you need more control.

Comment: You should use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` that are build on top of GCD. `NSOperation`s are cancellable, `NSOperationQueue` has `operations` and `operationCount` properties.

Comment: @MartinR no GCD methods to deal with it? Basically, NSOperationQueue can do all this stuff?

Comment: @ImanouPetit GCD has 4 default queues. How can I access one of them? Any identifier? I see it is easy to access the main one - NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, GCD is good for light-weight concurrency management. To suspend a dispatch queue, it's simply `dispatch_suspend(queue)`(only queue created by urself, neither main queues nor global queues). In ur case, `NSOperationQueue` is more suitable